# How to pre populate chosen multiselct dropdown on edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen multiselect drop down in my sample project

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBranch, Model.BranchList, "Select", new { @class = "select-chosen form-control", @tabindex = "2", @id = "BranchId", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

and my model is

```
public string[] SelectedBranch { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BranchList { get; set; }
```

The issue I am facing is I am not able to display the selected values on editing the already added data. I am getting all the selected values from the db in Cntroller

. Please let me know what I have to do to achieve it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ListBoxFor()` (and without `new { multiple="multiple" }`) to generate a multiple select that binds to your model

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedBranch, Model.BranchList, "Select", new { @class = "select-chosen form-control", @tabindex = "2", @id = "BranchId" })
```

Comment: If my SelectedBranch was a string instead of string array then can I do the same

Comment: No. A `ListBoxFor()` generates a `<select multiple>` which posts back an array of values, therefore you property needs to be `IEnumerable`. On the other hand, if you use `DropDownListFor()` (without adding `new { multiple = "multiple" }` then it will bind to a property which is `string` since it only posts back a single value

Comment: As a side note,since this question, I added a more detailed explanation to a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481) which explains why `DropDownListFor()` with `new { multiple = "multiple" }` does not work.

Comment: My issue is that I am having string as model and I am have all the pre selected values as a comma seperated string is it possible

Comment: You editing data, therefore you should always be using a view model specific to the view, and that view model can contain a property `IEnumerable<string> SelectedBranch` and then you can use `String.Join(...)` when you map the view model to the data model before saving, and `String.Split()` in the other direction. But why are you saving a comma separated string? That is considered terrible practice - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) for just one of many Q/A on this site explaining why its bad.

Comment: Tanx @Stephen you are awsome

Comment: I know its an old Post, but that kind of strange, What user posted in question is working for me on many pages except one, Just one page where its not working so I have to replace it with answer which is given here