# ASP.net MVC MultiSelectList with ListBox in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am following the [blog](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support) to use ASP.Net MVC MultiSelectList in my app. I am running into

> "System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable." error.

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5.2.3. My controller has an action populates a MultiSelectList and assigns it to a ViewBag.stations variable like this:

```
var qryResult = DB.getPatientInfoCompleted(StationIDs);            
var theseStations = qryResult.Select(x => new
{
    StationID = x.StationID,
    StationName = x.StationName
}).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
ViewBag.station = new MultiSelectList(theseStations, "StationID", "StationName");
```

The razor view has

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("station2", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.stations, new { multiple = "multiple"})
</td>

<td>
    @Html.ListBox("station", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.stations, new { @id = "lstMultiSelect", @class = "btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle menu-width" })
</td>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: Do not use `DropDownList()` with `new { multiple = "multiple"}` to generate a multiple select - use `ListBox()` or `ListBoxFor()` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481) for an explanation (and in addition to Peter B's answer, remove `.Distinct()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `OrderBy(x => x)` clause. Anonymous objects do not implement `IComparable` and thus can not be ordered.

You should probably be using `OrderBy(x => x.StationName)` instead.

As an alternative you can also create a class for this simple object, make it implement `IComparable`, while choosing an appropriate compare operation.

***Update:***

To define a class to replace the anonymous object, look at what was used for the anonymous object: `new { StationID = ... , StationName = ... }` and write a class that exactly mimics those properties (I assumed them to be `int` and `string`).

Then we make the class implement the interface `IComparable<...>` by adding it behind the class name. The compiler will then force us to implement the method `CompareTo(...)` which is the only method prescribed by the interface. For the implementation I just chose to compare a single property (StationName) that seemed relevant and good for this purpose. Our new `CompareTo` method can now be used by the Linq `OrderBy` clause.

```
public class MyModel : IComparable<MyModel>
{
    public int StationID { get; set; }
    public string StationName { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(MyModel other)
    {
        return this.StationName.CompareTo(other.StationName);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean making the LINQ statement (ie qryResult) to implement IComparable, or MultiSelectList?  Could you show me how?  Thanks.