# How to get and set multiple checkbox values based on serverside data using bootstrap multiselect plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have dropdownlist which contains multiple values. and user can select any no of values by clicking the checkbox infront of the value as shown below.

[image]

Following is my c# code.

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Detail, new SelectList(ViewBag.detailList, "Value", "Text"), new { id = "det" , multiple= "multiple"})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#det').multiselect();
});
```

When user click save button I want to get the user selected list. I am using following code to get the values.

`$("#det").val()`

But the above value is empty. How to get the existing selected value?

And also I want to show the values as selected based on server side values.
I am creating model and set model property with hardcoded values as below.

`model.Detail = "Cheese, Tomatoes";`

But these values are not getting selected in dropdownlist as well.

Used plugin here - [link](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#options)
Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `Detail` property needs to be `IEnumerable<string>`, not `string` and if your generating options with values "Cheese" and "Tomatoes", then you set `model.Detail = new List<string>{ "Cheese", "Tomatoes" };`

Comment: And if `ViewBag.detailList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` it is just pointless to create another identical one using `new SelectList(ViewBag.detailList, "Value", "Text")`

Comment: And use `ListBoxFor()` not `DropDownListFor()` to generate a multiple select.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add multiple= "multiple" in the attributes for multiselect to work.

```
@Html.DropDownList(m => m.Detail, new SelectList(ViewBag.detailList, "Value", "Text"), 
         new { id = "det", multiple= "multiple" });
```

to set the values:

```
<script>
    var selectedValues = @model.Detail;

    var dataarray = selectedValues.split(",");

    // Set the value
    $("#det").val(dataarray);
    $("#det").multiselect("refresh");
</script>
```

Comment: Its working correctly. What I want to find is how can I send multi value from server and selected them on client side based on server side values.

Comment: i was just typing that :). Updated the answer

Comment: But I think you have combined both razor code as well as jquery. I can't used my selected values in jquery side since I am getting selected values in razor. Am I correct?

Comment: Razor ultimately compiles cshtml into html. The above code would look like `var selectedValues = "Cheese, Tomatoes"` in the browser. Now, you want to bind the values in your `model.Detail` property to the dropdown. So you need to get the value to a javascript variable.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `DropDownList()` to create a multiple select, use `ListBoxFor()` (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481))

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use @Html.ListBoxFor that works best with Multiselect js.

In order to get the values for selected options, I have created the following client side code which returns list of value in form of String arrays

```
function GetDropDownVal() {
        var selectidList = [];
        var selectedItem = $("#ListQueCatId").val();
 // .multiselect("getChecked") can also be used.
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedItem.length; i++) {
                selectidList.push(selectedItem[i]);
            }
        }
        return selectidList;
    }
```

This is how I have implemented the code 
View Side Code

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ListQueCatId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AllQueCat as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control listQueCatIdDdl" })
```

Javascript Code

```
 $(".listQueCatIdDdl").multiselect({ noneSelectedText: "--Select Category(s)--" });
```

Also, make sure to bind a model property of Type List in my case, ListQueCatId is List< Guid>, hence while you post the form, you will get the selected values in your model.

Also, I don't think there is need to add multiple attribute as the plugin is meant for selecting multiple values.

Comment: `var selectedItem = $("#ListQueCatId").val();` already is an array of the selected option values. To create another identical array is utterly pointless