# Multiselect MVC5.2 Html.EnumDropDownListFor() fails when bound to a collection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to implement an MVC webpage, that contains a dropdown for enums.
It works fine, when bound to a single-valued property, like `MyEnum MyProperty {get;set;}`
Now, I'd like to turn it into a multiselect list - but in this case `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor()` fails with the following exception:

> Return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[[MyNamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, MyEnum=null]]' is not supported.
>   Parameter name: expression'

A similar thing for string collections works fine.
Any ideas?

**Model**

```
public IEnumerable StringValues;

[Display(Name = "Works fine for strings")]
public IEnumerable<string> StringCollectionProperty { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Fails for enums")]
[EnumDataType(typeof(MyEnum))]
public IEnumerable<ProcessingStatus> MyEnumCollectionProperty { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
// This works fine
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StringCollectionProperty, Model.StringValues, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })

// This fails with the error above
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyEnumCollectionProperty, "Please select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: The first does not actually work fine - it needs to be `ListBoxFor()` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481).

Comment: What is typeof `ProcessingStatus`?