# Remove 'multiple' attribute from chosen dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-chosen, dropdownlistfor

I am using ‘choosen-select’ for multiselect or single select dropdown list.

Depends on condition dropdown change from single select to multiselect.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPlants, new MultiSelectList(Model.PlantList, "Value", "Text", Model.PreSelectedPlants.Select(a => a.Value))
                        , new { @class = "chosen-select", ID = "ddlplants", Style = "width:100%", data_placeholder = "Choose Plants..", multiple = "multiple" })
```

I am trying to remove ‘multiple’ from dropdownlist attribute using jquery but it’s not working.

Please any one helps me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot remove it from the Razor code you've posted in the question ..? If you want to do it in jQuery use `attr()`, but note that you'll need to destroy and re-initialise the chosen library you've instantiated on the select for the change to be picked up

Comment: Why are you adding `multiple = "multiple"` if your do not want it to be multiple?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want single select and multiselect in one dropdown depends on condition.Dropdown change from single to multiple and viceversa.

Comment: That makes no sense - there are multiple errors in your code. First a `<select>` binds to a simple value (say `int`) but a `<select multiple>` binds to an array (say `IEnumerable<int>` so your would need 2 separate properties. Second To create a `<select multiple>` that binds correctly you need `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: Third using `new MultiSelectList()` with `PlantList` which appears to already be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is just pointless extra overhead - it generates another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Forth, the last parameter in your `new MultiSelectList()` is also pointless because its ignored. Its the value of `SelectedPlants` that determines what is selected