# How to get multiselect dropdown id morethan one using datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my asp.net code for dropdown: iam unable get the multiple selected ids of checkboxes.

```
@if (ViewBag.EventContentTypeId == Convert.ToInt32(EventContentType.Events))
{
    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group input" style="padding-left:0">
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("EventCategoryDDL", @ViewBag.EventCategories as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control call-checkbox", @multiple = "multiple" })
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and this is my datatable code:

```
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    oTable
        .columns(12).search($("#EventCategoryDDL option:selected").val())
        .draw();
         return false;
});
```

here in this line

```
.columns(12).search($("#EventCategoryDDL option:selected").val())
```

if selected multiple checkbox ids also i am getting only one id . and iam using jquery multiselect plugin.

```
$('#EventCategoryDDL').multiselect({
    placeholder: '-- Select Category --',
    selectAll: true
});
```

and this is small  multiselect code of plugin.

Comment: Not related, but always use `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()` to generate a `<select multiple>` - refer [Why does the DropDownListFor lose the multiple selection after Submit but the ListBoxFor doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: Because `.val()` only returns the value of the first one (refer [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)). Use `$("#EventCategoryDDL).val()` to return an array of the selected values