# Select2 Placeholder Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 Multiselect html element. While rendering the placeholder is not displaying, but if I select and remove the item, the placeholder is displaying. I have no idea how to make it work. Please advise.

**Initially**

[image]

**While Selection**

[image]

**After removing the items**

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Vendor, new SelectList(Model.Status), "Search Status", new { @id = "advanced-search-lsc-status", @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple", data_placeholder = "Select Status" })


$('#advanced-search-status').select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
            placeholder: function(){
                $(this).data('placeholder');
            },
            width: '100%'
        });
```

Comment: Not related, but use `ListBoxFor()`and delete the `new { multiple = "multiple" }` - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I tried it, still the issue exists :( btw good info

Comment: I did say _Not related_ :) - its was just to fix the other issue with your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just now found out that what was wrong, initially the width was set to 0 which hides the placeholder.

[image]

Just manipulated using this jquery code.

```
.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field{
    width:initial!important;
}
```

now it works

[image]

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
.select2-container .select2-search--inline:first-child {
    float: none;
}
.select2-container .select2-search--inline:first-child .select2-search__field{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Using the "first-child" selector assures that the search field doesn't take up extra room when options are selected -- it only maintains its width when the multi-select is empty

Answer (score 1):

Simply add attr placeholder

```
$("#advanced-search-status").attr("placeholder", "Select Status");
```

or

```
$('#advanced-search-status').select2({
    placeholder: "Select Status"
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Parth for the quick response, but i already tried these. Still having the issue