# MultiSelectList change dynamically ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-select2

I'm using this code to generate a multi-select2. Tags is a MultiSelectList.

```
@Html.DropDownList("mail-to", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Tags, String.Empty, htmlAttributes: new { multiple = "", @class = "form-control select2 select2-multiple" })

$("#mail-to").select2({
           minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
           closeOnSelect: false,
       });
```

It works great. Now I want to change the select options with another ViewBag based on a checkbox field checked change event.
Is there a way to change select2 data populated with this type of list or a MVC way to do it?

What I've tryed:

```
$("#mail-to").select2({
    tags: @ViewBag.TagsArea, //or tags: @Html.Raw((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TagsArea)
                    });
```

Comment: Not related, but it needs to be `ListBox()`, not `DropDownList()` - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: And it would be `tags: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.TagsArea)),` to convert the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to a javascript array

Comment: Changed to list box, thanks for the info. But is not working, writing tags that way gives `Option tags is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element`

Comment: What version of select2 are you using?

Comment: Was using 4.0.2, updated to 4.0.6, still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it:

```
var areas = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Tags)) ;    
$("#mail-to").empty();
     $.each(areas, function (index, element) {
         $("#mail-to").append($('<option/>', {
            value: element.Value, text: element.Text
             }));
     });
```