# multiselect list model binding in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor, multi-select

I have 3 multiselect dropdown lists. When I make multiple selections from each dropdown lists and submit I can see that the results are being posted but doesn't get passed to the controller.

my view

```
    @model Facility.AdgarWeb.ViewModels.MailingConfigVM

    @using (Html.BeginForm("New", "MailingConfig"))
    {
@*Company List Dropdown*@
<div class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown--companyList">
    <h3 class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown__title">Wybierz Budynki</h3>
    <div class="dropdown companiesDropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="companiesButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select Building
        </button>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.allBuildings)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.allBuildings, new MultiSelectList(Model.allBuildings, "Id", "Name"), new { @class="dropdown-menu", @multiple="true" })
    </div>
</div>

@*Classification List Dropdown*@
<div class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown--classificationList">
    <h3 class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown__title">Wybierz Klasyfikacje</h3>
    <div class="dropdown classificationDropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="classificationButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select Classification
        </button>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.allServices)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.allServices, new MultiSelectList(Model.allServices, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "dropdown-menu", @multiple = "true" })
    </div>
</div>
@*Users List Dropdown*@
<div class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown--usersList">
    <h3 class="mailingConfiguration__modal__dropDown__title">Wybierz Użytkowników</h3>
    <div class="dropdown usersDropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="usersButton" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Select Users
        </button>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.allUsers)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.allUsers, new MultiSelectList(Model.allUsers, "Id", "UserName"), new { @class = "dropdown-menu", @multiple = "true" })
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="New" value="Submit">
}
```

viewmodel

```
    public class MailingConfigVM
{
    [Display(Name = "Buildings")]
    public IEnumerable<Building> allBuildings { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Services")]
    public IEnumerable<Facility.Model.Service> allServices { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    public IEnumerable<User> allUsers { get; set; }

}
```

controller

```
        public ActionResult Create()
    {
        if (!SessionControlService.CheckIsLoginStillTrue(_loginsService, HttpContext))
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

        MailingConfigVM vm = new MailingConfigVM();
        vm.allBuildings = _buildingService.GetBuildings();
        vm.allServices = _serviceService.GetServices();
        vm.allUsers = _userService.GetUsers().Where(user => user.Roles.Any(r => r.Id <= 4));
        var buildings = _buildingService.GetBuildings().ToList();
        return View(vm);
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(MailingConfigVM mailingConfigVM)
    {
        if (!SessionControlService.CheckIsLoginStillTrue(_loginsService, HttpContext))
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        if (!User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "MailingConfig");
    }
```

The create controller populates the forms with datas for selection and New controller is httppost. I want the selected items to be passed to this controller, but after POST the result is "COUNT=0" on each of the list.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind a`<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects, which is what your properties are. A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values.

Your model needs 3 additional properties (note this assumes that the `Id` properties of your `Building`, `Service` and `User` model are typeof `int`)

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedBuildings { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedServices { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedUsers { get; set; }
```

In addition, you should be making the collection properties `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and using `new SelectList(...)` in the controller, not the view to create the options, for example

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllBuildings { get; set; }
....
```

and in the controller

```
vm.AllBuildings = new SelectList(_buildingService.GetBuildings(), "Id", "Name");
```

Finally, in order to bind correctly, you must use `ListBoxFor()`, not `DropDownListFor()` as explained in [Why does the DropDownListFor lose the multiple selection after Submit but the ListBoxFor doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Your view code will now be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedBuildings)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedBuildings, Model.AllBuildings, new { @class="dropdown-menu" })
....
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedServices, Model.AllServices, new { @class="dropdown-menu" })
....
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!