# selections do not appear in the order in which they were selected - Select2 js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, jquery-select2, multi-select

I'm working with Select2 js(version 4.0.3) with ASP.NET MVC. 
I have added reference of js and css files on Layout page.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/select2.min.js"></scr`ipt>

Here is my view page code where I'm using it.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlatformIds, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Platforms, new { @class = "form-control select2", @multiple = true })
</div>
```

For instance, platforms having data like Vitro, Nop and Woo.
When user select any option, it sort in alphabetical order by default.

How can we stop that alphabetical order?

I have seen same issue over here: [In multi-select, selections do not appear in the order in which they were selected](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106) 
But don't know where to fix, as I'm using min js file.

Comment: Not related, but you need to use `ListBoxFor()` for correct binding - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: A `<select>` posts back the values of the selected options in the order that they are rendered - it makes no difference what order they are selected

Comment: And what I need to do if I want in order selected by user?

Comment: try this link - https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106

Comment: @SahilSharma: Thanks but I think you should see all the things mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Hina Khuman - The default ordering of selection items is a feature of select2. This link I have referred you to is a bug opened about the same. Try to go through the answers, there are few workarounds mentioned.

Comment: @SahilSharma: I have gone through that thread already as I mentioned in the question with pinned this thread link, yes there are workarounds it, but seems not appropriate with my case. That's why I asked it here.