# MVC List<SelectListItem> with groups creating optgroup for each item

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I'm having an issue where I'm creating a `List<SelectListItem>` with `optgroups` but instead of creating an `optgroup` per group of `SelectListItem` it's creating a new `SelectListGroup` per `SelectListItem`. It's got me a bit confused because there aren't any duplicated `SelectListGroup`'s in my code.

Here is an example:

Expected Result:

```
<select datatag="data-States=''" class="form-control filter-select" data-multi-select="" id="States" multiple="multiple" name="States">
    <optgroup label="MA">
    <option value="01602">01602</option>
    <option value="02743">02743</option>
    <option value="01107">01107</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Actual Result:

```
<select datatag="data-States=''" class="form-control filter-select" data-multi-select="" id="States" multiple="multiple" name="States">
<optgroup label="MA">
<option value="01602">01602</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="MA">
<option value="02743">02743</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="MA">
<option value="01107">01107</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Method:

```
 public ManifestFilterDropDownItem ReturnManifestFilterDataBasedOnTotalDataSet(IEnumerable<ManifestTableItem> data, bool isUserASR) {
            IEnumerable<SelectListGroup> stateGroups = data.Select(x => x.AddrState.ToUpper()).Distinct().Select(x => new SelectListGroup() {
                Name = x
            });

            IList<SelectListItem> stateZipSelectListItems = data.GroupBy(x => x.AddrZip).Select(x => new SelectListItem() {
                Text = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key) ? "Empty" : x.Key,
                Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Key) ? "" : x.Key,
                Group = stateGroups.Where(y => y.Name == data.Where(p => p.AddrZip == x.Key).First().AddrState.ToUpper()).Single()
            }).OrderBy(x => x.Group.Name).ToList();


            var manifestItem = new ManifestFilterDropDownItem {
                States = stateZipSelectListItems
            return manifestItem;
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FSVendor.Models.Manifest {
    public class ManifestFilterViewModel {
        public ManifestFilterViewModel() {

        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DataTag => $"data-{Name}=''";
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model FSVendor.Models.Manifest.ManifestFilterViewModel

<label>States:</label>
@Html.DropDownList(Model.Name, Model.SelectListItems, new { @class = "form-control filter-select", data_multi_select = "", multiple = "multiple", @Model.DataTag })
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You query is creating a new `SelectListGroup` for each `SelectListItem`, even though each `SelectListGroup` has the same value.

Modify the query to group the data, and then create a new `SelectListGroup` for each group

```
// Initialize model
var model = new ManifestFilterDropDownItem
{
    States = new List<SelectListItem>
}
var states = data.GroupBy(x => x.AddrState); // group by state
foreach (var group in states)
{
    // Create a SelectListGroup
    var optionGroup = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key };
    // Add SelectListItem's
    foreach (var item in group)
    {   
        model.States.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = item.AddrZip,
            Text = item.AddrZip,
            Group = optionGroup
        })
    }
}
return model;
```

Alternatively, you can use one of the overloads of the `SelectList` constructor

```
var model = new ManifestFilterDropDownItem
{
    States = new SelectList(data, "AddrZip", "AddrZip", "AddrState", null, null)
};
return model;
```

As a side note, do not use `DropDownList()` to create a `<select multiple>`. You need to use `ListBoxFor()` in order for 2-way model binding to work. Refer [Why does the DropDownListFor lose the multiple selection after Submit but the ListBoxFor doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: Hi, admittedly I haven't gotten around to testing your code yet but how am I creating a new `SelectListGroup` for each `SelectListItem`? I select a distinct set of `AddrState` and then loop around then set the grouping based on the zip for the state?

Comment: Okay, I tested your code and it doesn't work. It doesnt actually work when I crepate one group and try to group it all under. I believe it is due to a separate issue which I am discovering now

Comment: I think it was due to another issue which I was having. I back tracked and used your suggestions and removed the code which I thought was causing issues and it worked, cheers bratta

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `ManifestTableItem` class has at least this structure:

```
class ManifestTableItem {
  public string AddrState { get ; set ; }
  public string AddrZip { get ; set ; }
}
```

To make state appear as a group in the  `selectlist`, you need to use this overload:

```
new SelectList(data, nameof(ManifestTableItem.AddrZip), nameof(ManifestTableItem.AddrZip), null, nameof(ManifestTableItem.AddrState));
```