# multiselect Set values as selected in dropdown in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, multi-select

> I need a way to set already selected values in a multi select dropdown
>   in a edit view in a web application (ASP.NET, Mvc 5) :

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("EntityId", selectList: (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EntityId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control select2", multiple = "multiple" })
   </div>
</div>
```

//Controller

```
  ViewBag.EntityId = new SelectList(context.CompanyEntity.Where(x => x.UserProfile.Any(u => u.UserProfileId == id)), "EntityId", "EntityName");
```

> I need a edit view by set selecting already selected values.

Comment: You cannot have the same name for the property you are binding to and the `SelectList` (refer [Can the ViewBag name be the same as the Model property name in a DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist). Your model needs an `IEnumerable<int>` property to bind to, and you set the value of that in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

Comment: And you cannot use `DropDownList` for a `<select multiple>` - you need to use `ListBoxFor()` - refer [Why does the DropDownListFor lose the multiple selection after Submit but the ListBoxFor doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725358/why-does-the-dropdownlistfor-lose-the-multiple-selection-after-submit-but-the-li/40732481#40732481)

Comment: thank you for your reply but i can't use Select 2  with listBox ?

Comment: Yes of course - it generates a `<select multiple>` - read the links I gave you

Comment: Thank You So Mush